# Docker failed to initialize, docker wont open after installing it

Tags: docker

When I try to open docker desktop I get this error:

```
Docker failed to initialize
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

[image]

I tried reinstalling docker, installing wsl 2, enabling intel vm on bios

Comment: check the `.NET Framework` whether correct version is installed in your machine by comparing with the `Docker` requirement.

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov my current version is 7.0.203, I didn't find the specific version needed on the docker website

Comment: if you have antivirus installed, can you also try to reinstall the Docker by disabling the antivirus